# Week Incrementation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dayofweek, gettimeofday

I'm working on a reminders application using Phonegap [Javascript + Html5] in which the user enters the weekly task he wants to be reminded of and I'm supposed to alert a notification every week on that day.

Now the point is: I use Phonegap Local Notification Plugin to alert the notifications, this plugin takes a date to alert on time.

How can I give the needed date everyweek .. i.e: How Can I increment the counter when the day ends ?

Usually if the date if preknown: I use this function:

```
 if (typeof plugins !== "undefined")
                       {
                        var RId = 0;
                        var rDate =new Date();
                        var RemDate = reminder_deadline.split("T")[0];
                        var RemTimeB = reminder_deadline.split("T")[1];
                        var RemTime = RemTimeB.split("Z")[0];
                        var RYear = RemDate.split("-")[0];
                        var RMonth = RemDate.split("-")[1];
                        var RMonth = RMonth-1;
                        var RDay = RemDate.split("-")[2];
                        var RHour = RemTime.split(":")[0];
                        var RMinute = RemTime.split(":")[1];
                        var RSecond = RemTime.split(":")[2];
                        alert(RYear+".."+RMonth+".."+RDay+".."+RHour+".."+RMinute+".."+RSecond);
                        rDate.setFullYear(RYear);
                        rDate.setMonth(RMonth);
                        rDate.setDate(RDay);
                        rDate.setHours(RHour);
                        rDate.setMinutes(RMinute);
                        rDate.setSeconds(RSecond);
                        plugins.localNotification
                        .add({ 
                            date: rDate,
                            message: reminder_name, 
                            id: RId
                             });
                             }
                             RId++;
             }
```

But now the user will just enter Monday ... & I'm supposed to notify him every Monday ... 
So is that possible to be made ?

Comment: What server-side scripting technology are you using?

Comment: I just use Javascript. Html & Sqlite .. & I use java for the notifications, but it's made with a plugin that I didn't implement myself.

Comment: Sana... This is probably better done in the java - rather than javascript, as you'd run into a bunch of problems as it currently stands. There is an option currently to "repeat daily" -- so you just need to find that option in the java side of things and manipulate it to set a repeating weekly option... I would say it's to do with line 56 of `AlarmHelper.java` https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/LocalNotification/AlarmHelper.java

Comment: But I know nothing about Java, how can I do it :(

Comment: Should I just quit Phonegap & start learning Java & objective C ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var today = new Date();
var nextWeek = new Date();
nextWeek.setDate(nextWeek.getDate() + 7);
```

---

Here's a snippet that gives you the last monday. If you need any other day, just edit the line `var daysOffMonday` accordingly (0=Sunday, 1=Monday, ...)

Then with the snippet above you can fetch the next monday, and the one next to that, etc.

```
​var today = new Date();

​var dayOfWeek = today.getDay();
var daysOffMonday = 1 - dayOfWeek;
var lastMonday = new Date();
lastMonday.setDate(lastMonday.getDate() + daysOffMonday);

​alert(lastMonday);​
```

Comment: `getDate()` returns the current day, e.g. 12 for today. It'd be quite a surprise if `new Date( 19 )` worked. Not to mention that this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: sorry, I indeed was to fast... edited (and tested ;)) the code

Comment: ah and i see poster has updated the question, and now this indeed does not answer his question (anymore), although it could be useful :)